# Build error occurred in Vercel when Deploying NextJs : Invalid JSON Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

Actually on my laptop it is working well using `npm run dev` and when doing `npm run build` it is also worked without any error.

[image: Build Success Image]

And when deploying it to vercel I am getting error of:

```
13:21:05.897    info  - Collecting page data...
13:21:06.193    > Build error occurred
13:21:06.195    FetchError: invalid json response body at https://bcanepaltu.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=200 reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
13:21:06.195        at /vercel/path0/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
13:21:06.196        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
13:21:06.196        at async getStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/posts/[id].js:39:16)
13:21:06.196        at async buildStaticPaths (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:16:80)
13:21:06.196        at async /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js:26:622
13:21:06.196        at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/telemetry/trace/trace.js:6:584) {
13:21:06.196      type: 'invalid-json'
13:21:06.196    }
13:21:06.227    error Command failed with exit code 1.
13:21:06.227    info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
13:21:06.247    Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

So I am trying to fetch JSON of my WordPress site and generating posts whereas
https://bcanepaltu.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=200 working well on dev and while seeing on this URL
So why it is giving error of invalid JSON token ?

Comment: I have same problem.

Comment: actually fixed it ... by disabling the firewall on Cloudflare...
Cloudflare bot protection and firewall protection blocked it...
fixed by disabling bot fight mode and firewall of cloudflare.